# Show video composition

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to show on my webpage a video from twilio that was recorded.
The REST call that I made from twilio (get composition) returns a binary file and I want to use it to show the video.
I can't use the url from twilio directly to the video src because it needs authentication and I do it on the back-end.
I can do it using the binary and encoding it to base64, the problem is that for large videos the webpage has a lazy load due to the download of the large file.

Also, I don't have the binary locally in my server, and therefore I'm getting the binary each time I need to see the video.
Can anyone help me to know how is the best way to show the video and to make it possible to be load by chunks with buffering? Because I can create a webpage that only downloads the binary and use it directly on the src of the video too, but with that I can't return x seconds back on the video or foward, I can only see it from the beggining to the end without missing anything.

Many thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'd recommend that you download the video and store it yourself under a URL that you can set in a `<video>` element. That will save you downloading the video from Twilio each time and give you the control over the playback.